# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_keyword' Sikuli Error

Tags: testing, dockerfile, automated-tests, robotframework, sikuli

I'm facing the same problem ,
I want to test my application with robot Framework and Sikuli on docker .
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Update packages and install dependencies

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    openjdk-11-jre-headless \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Robot Framework and Sikuli library
RUN pip install robotframework
RUN pip install robotframework-SikuliLibrary

# Download and install SikuliX
RUN wget https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/2.0.4/+download/sikulixide-2.0.4.jar  -O /root/sikulix.jar


# Set environment variables for SikuliX
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
ENV SIKULIX_HOME /root
ENV SIKULIX_JAR /root/sikulix.jar

# Copy test files into the container
COPY . /tests

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /tests

# Execute tests with Robot Framework
CMD ["robot", "--outputdir", "results", "test.robot"]
```

and here is my test script :

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Test d'IHM par sikuli et robot framework
Library    SikuliLibrary    port=4119   timeout=3.0    mode=REMOTE
Library    Process
Library    OperatingSystem
Suite Setup     Start Sikuli Process  
Suite Teardown   Run Keywords    Close Application     ${APP_PATH}    AND   Stop Remote Server

*** Variables ***
${IMAGES_PATH}        //tests/SikuliImages
${APP_PATH}           //tests/FHF_App.exe

***Test Cases***
Open IHM
    Open IHM Application
Read Images
   Read Images From Path
Navigate IHM Application Buttons
    Navigate Buttons
*** Keywords ***
Start Sikuli Process
    ${port}=    Set Environment Variable    SIKULI_SERVER_PORT    4119  # Port souhaité, par exemple 4119
    Run    java -jar sikulix.jar -p ${port}    
    Sleep    3s  # Attendre que le processus Sikuli démarre
Read Images From Path 
     Add Image Path    ${IMAGES_PATH}
Open IHM Application
    Open Application    ${APP_PATH}
Navigate Buttons
     
    Wait Until Screen Contain     pauseButtonPull.png   timeout=30
    Click    pauseButtonPull.png
    Wait Until Screen Contain     pausePanel.png    timeout=40 
    
    Click    pauseButtonDown.png
    Click    PexpButtonPull.png
    Wait Until Screen Contain    PexpPanel.png    timeout=10
    Click    PexpButtonDown.png
```

When I run the test I got the following error :

```
Test :: Test d'IHM par sikuli et robot framework
Open IHM | FAIL |
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_keyword'
Read Images | FAIL |
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_keyword'
Navigate IHM Application Buttons | FAIL |
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_keyword'
Test :: Test d'IHM par sikuli et robot framework | FAIL |
Suite teardown failed:
Several failures occurred:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_keyword'

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_keyword'

3 tests, 0 passed, 3 failed
```

Can anyone help me with that please ?

I don't know if is it a Sikuli problem or docker. The same test pass on local (windows) but not on docker

Answer (score 0):

You must install correct Sikuli in the container.
You should look for sikuli-linux archive and not the sikuli IDE.

Also the way to start Sikuli is not with `Run`.
You should use `Start Sikuli Process` if library is imported with `mode=NEW`. Consult the documentation [here](https://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html).

Another thing is the version of Sikuli that you should use the newest, 2.0.5.

Comment: firstly ,thank you so much , annother thing , you said that 'Run' is not a way to start Sikuli . What is the correct way to run Sikuli